# SSL install on Apache, lost the key file

Tags: ssl, key

I am attempting to try to install my SSL certificate on a server and I have lost my key file that was generated when I was creating the CSR file for the SSL application.  I am fairly certain that this is a unique file and simply creating a new CSR file wont make the key file that I need.  Is there anything that I can do to get the same key and CSR file that I had before?  I used godaddy to get the certificate if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's nothing you can do without the original key. Some CAs will reissue a certificate due to a lost key, others you'll be paying again.

Answer (score 4):

yes there is a solution. Go to your godaddy account, ssl certs, and re-key it. Before this you have to create a new key and CSR. When you have the CSR, do what i said above logging to godaddy

Comment: with this you dont have to purchase a new SSL cert. Just re-key your old cert with a new key and CSR